# c9 IDE having trouble linking my angular.js file in html file

Tags: html, angularjs

my angular.min.js file is located in client/js

so in my html i am using

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../client/js/angular.min.js"></script>`

Is this wrong?

Please help`

Comment: Where is your HTML file and how do you visit your html?

Comment: HTML is located in public/index.html

Comment: Show your directory structure. Did you deploy to a server? Or open the html directly?

Comment: please tell me if this imgur link is OK.  It shows my structure.  http://i.imgur.com/qO71g5F.jpg